# Reading serial device copies output to input

Tags: serial-port, command-line-interface, io-redirection

I have a device connected to a serial port that provides a simple command line. My goal is ultimately to interact with it via Expect. I've run into a problem, though—when I read the device's output with `cat /dev/ttyS0` or `screen /dev/ttyS0`, it decides to use its own output as input.

```
>> BOOTING <<

Available commands:
  help                 Show detailed help
  test                 Run tests; see help for details

prompt>
```

Ideally, it would wait here for a return and then execute a command. In reality, what I see (without any input from me) is something along these lines:

```
prompt>  Rn ests se hlp fo etis
  Command 'Rn' not recognized. Enter 'help' for a list of choices.
prompt> ogizd. nter'hel' fo a lis of coie.
  Command 'ogizd.' not recognized. Enter 'help' for a list of choices.
prompt>  coics.
  Command 'coics.' not recognized. Enter 'help' for a list of choices.
prompt> d. Ener 'elp'for  listof coies
  Command 'd.' not recognized. Enter 'help' for a list of choices.
```

And so on, until I halt the `cat`. Interestingly, restarting it will yield no output (until I power cycle the device, at which point this feedback starts anew), which suggests to me that it's talking to itself only when I observe its output. The missing characters corroborate this suggestion. Redirecting `cat` to a file changes nothing.

The code for the command line is not mine. Other users have had no such issue.

What might be going wrong here, and how might I fix it?

Comment: Is it safe to assume you don't have a serial port with hardware echo? Have you disable software echo on your port?

Comment: @MarcosG. That is a safe assumption. I've not disabled software echo, but I definitely didn't enable it, and I've used this port just fine for similar things in the past.

Comment: Try to run `stty -F /dev/ttyS0 -echo ` before running `cat` just in case.

Comment: @MarcosG. That did the trick. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have, either:

-A hardware echo on your device. If so, you should be able to disable it with a switch.

-Software echo on your driver. To turn that off you can run:

```
stty -F /dev/ttyS0 -echo
```

That should make the behaviour of `cat` revert to what you expect.